# Parse line space from database table as HTML in final rendered PHP page

Tags: mysql, database, html-parsing

One of the fields in our PHP page is a description. Occasionally there are line spaces included to indicate a new paragraph. However, when pulling this data from the database table the text is rendered in one block without the spaces. How can I parse text from database table with the line-space in the final rendered PHP page? Thanks!

This is the part of the code that pulls the text from the database, which includes a function to parse anything beginning with http:// as a clickable link:

NB: **$det[9]** is the text

```
 <?php 
    echo preg_replace_callback(
        '/http:\/\/([,\%\w.\-_\/\?\=\+\&\~\#\$]+)/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return \'<a href="http://\'.  $matches[1] .\'">\'.  $matches[1] .\'</a>\';'
        ),
        $det[9]
    );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u search this function  [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br)

```
<?php
$description = "This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r";
echo nl2br($description);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
This<br />
is<br />
a<br />
string<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! That looks like it would be suitable - however I already have some code parsing http:// as HTML for this piece of text, so I'm not sure where to place the nl2br function. Can you amend the code in the original post? I will then try it.

Comment: i will try to wrap it all with the function like : $text = preg_replace_callback(
        '/http:\/\/([,\%\w.\-_\/\?\=\+\&\~\#\$]+)/',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return \'<a href="http://\'.  $matches[1] .\'">\'.  $matches[1] .\'</a>\';'
        ),
        $det[9]
    ); echo nl2br($text);

Comment: Perect, job done! Many thanks for the accurate and very quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the text into a `<pre>` tag or use another html element with `white-space: pre;` style.